# Ruby Emoji unicode don't displayed some icons

Tags: javascript, ruby, debugging, emoji, codepoint

I'm using ruby 2.2.2, and Emoji
But for some reason some icons don't dispayed
For example (from http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode):

Unicode: U+26F5

Bytes (UTF-8): \xE2\x9B\xB5

Description: SAILBOAT

Maybe someone know, how I can fix it?

I know that it works in Java, JS, JRuby, and the problem is:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_code_points

Thanks!

```
// for JS
// for converting unicode code points and code pairs to their respective characters
convert = function(unicode) {
    if(unicode.indexOf("-") > -1) {
        var parts = [];
        var s = unicode.split('-');
        for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            var part = parseInt(s[i], 16);
            if (part >= 0x10000 && part <= 0x10FFFF) {
                var hi = Math.floor((part - 0x10000) / 0x400) + 0xD800;
                var lo = ((part - 0x10000) % 0x400) + 0xDC00;
                part = (String.fromCharCode(hi) + String.fromCharCode(lo));
            }
            else {
                part = String.fromCharCode(part);
            }
            parts.push(part);
        }
        return parts.join('');
    }
    else {
        var s = parseInt(unicode, 16);
        if (s >= 0x10000 && s <= 0x10FFFF) {
            var hi = Math.floor((s - 0x10000) / 0x400) + 0xD800;
            var lo = ((s - 0x10000) % 0x400) + 0xDC00;
            return (String.fromCharCode(hi) + String.fromCharCode(lo));
        }
        else {
            return String.fromCharCode(s);
        }
    }
};
```

This works for JavaScript, but if JS output is returned to ruby it doesn't work.

Comment: `puts "\u26F5"` works for me

Comment: Emojis do not display **where**? Btw, `puts "\u26F5" #⇒ ⛵`.

Comment: How are you trying to display this? Can you display other emoji? Perhaps your font doesn't have that particular one.

Comment: do not display simbols from U+D800 through U+DFFF... it looks 

['26F5'.hex].pack('U') #⇒ ⛵

, but not like

> ['1F601'.hex].pack('U') => ""

Comment:  `U+1F601` _grinning face with smiling eyes_ = `utf-8` sequence`0xF0`,`0x9F`,`0x98`,`0x81` however its `utf-16` equivalent = surrogate pair `U+d83d`,`U+de01` and surrogates can't be expressed in `utf-8`.